# Tally, tally, tally (from Top Gun: Maverick)

Tags: word-usage

What does this quote mean from the Top Gun: Maverick (at 36 minutes 46 seconds):

> 00:36:46,143 --> 00:36:49,212
> Tally, tally,
> tally! Maverick's coming in! Break left!

There are about a dozen definitions of 'tally' and I'm having a hard time finding the one that fits.

Some context: they are doing an exercise fight up in the sky and they made a bet on who shoots down who first.

The bet is considered to be won or lost after only one successful shot (otherwise, I would have thought that they are tallying the score of who shoots who how many times), as indicated by the rules of the bet:

> 00:36:13,977 --> 00:36:17,014
> Whoever gets shot down first
> has to do 200 push-ups.

Comment: This is probably USAF jargon.  Not generally used like this in English.  Try asking on [aviation.se]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Tally** is fighter pilot jargon meaning "enemy in sight".](https://www.military.com/undertheradar/2016/03/23-terms-only-fighter-pilots-understand)  It has nothing to do with keeping score in this context.